Collision handling in pygame
I am making a platformer game. I tried everything even rounding up the position before putting it in the rectangle. I can't find anything solving it. The game is pixel art (scaled with an aspect ratio so every thing should be slow). The player always overlaps with the ground. The gravity will always push the player down. I can;t find the solution anywhere.
class Player(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos=(10, -10), config=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.pos = pg.math.Vector2(self.rect.center)
        self.vel = pg.math.Vector2(0, 0)
        self.speed = 3
        self.max_speed = 15
        self.gravity = 1
        self.jump_strength = -3
        self.is_jumping = False
        self.idle_timer = 0

        self.colls = {"left": False, "right": False, "up": False, "down": False}


    def update(self, dt):
        self.rect.size = self.image.get_size()
        self.rect.center = self.pos

        if not self.colls["down"]:
            self.vel.y += self.gravity * dt
        else:
            self.vel.y = 0

        if self.keys["left"]:
            self.vel.x = -self.speed
        elif self.keys["right"]:
            self.vel.x = self.speed
        else:
            self.vel.x = 0

        if self.colls["down"]:
            if abs(self.vel.x) > 0:
                self.state = "run"
            else:
                self.state = "idle"
        elif self.is_jumping:
            self.state = "jump"

        self.colls = {key: False for key in self.colls}

    def handle_collisions(self, tiles):
        self.pos.x += self.vel.x
        self.rect.centerx = self.pos.x
        for tile in tiles:
            if self.rect.colliderect(tile.rect) and tile.type in TOUCHABLES:
                if self.vel.x > 0:
                    self.rect.right = tile.rect.left
                    self.colls["right"] = True
                elif self.vel.x < 0:
                    self.rect.left = tile.rect.right
                    self.colls["left"] = True
                self.pos.x = self.rect.centerx

        self.pos.y += self.vel.y
        self.rect.centery = int(self.pos.y)
        for tile in tiles:
            if self.rect.colliderect(tile.rect) and tile.type in TOUCHABLES:
                if self.vel.y > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = tile.rect.top
                    self.colls["down"] = True
                    self.is_jumping = False
                    self.vel.y = 0
                elif self.vel.y < 0:
                    self.rect.top = tile.rect.bottom
                    self.colls["up"] = True
                    self.vel.y = 0
                self.pos.y = self.rect.centery

        if self.colls["left"] or self.colls["right"]:
            self.vel.x = 0
        if self.colls["up"] or self.colls["down"]:
            self.vel.y = 0

